# what are all the components used to connect arduino and android

Tags: android, arduino

> i want to **send data** from android **smartphone to Arduino** AND **Arduino to android** but ***without using Bluetooth and Wifi***. 
>   What are all the ways? 
>   How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a OTG Cable.

You should create a generic driver to open a communication channel via USB to your Arduino.

Good luck

Comment: Or use a USB cable if your arduino has a USB host port.

Answer (score 0):

You have to communicate with devices via "Channels", either COM, Ethernet, or WiFi. Otherwise, it would be infeasible and meaningless to do so.

For a start, you can connect Arduino to PC, then communicate with Android phone via software client application on PC and which reads/sends to arduuino via serial port. This application interacts with Android via Wifi.

So in summary:

Arduino Board (Serial) <-> (Serial) PC Client App (WiFi) <-> Android App.

Some developers would create a service running on PC (XNL web service or WCF) that plays as a medium between Arduino and Android.